# MySQL - LEFT JOIN with LIKE % is extremely slow

Tags: mysql, magento, left-join

I have a query that runs extremely slow (about 50 seconds):

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `main_table`.`entity_id`, `url_rewrite`.`request_path` 
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `main_table`
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `w` 
      ON main_table.entity_id = w.product_id
LEFT JOIN `core_url_rewrite` AS `url_rewrite` 
      ON url_rewrite.product_id = main_table.entity_id 
      AND url_rewrite.is_system = 1  
      AND url_rewrite.category_id IS NULL 
      AND url_rewrite.store_id = 1 
      AND url_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'product/%'
```

The query comes from Magento, only the `SQL_NO_CACHE` was added by me to make the measurement more accurate.

Such long execution time is of course unacceptable. So I dumped the database and restored it on my development environment to investigate the issue. However on my development database the query is very fast - it runs in less than 0.1s.

**Question 1:**
What can be the cause of such long execution times on my production environment?
I haven't noticed any other queries being so slow on my production database.

To investigate further I modified the query a bit:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `main_table`.`entity_id`, `url_rewrite`.`request_path` 
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `main_table`
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `w` 
      ON main_table.entity_id = w.product_id
LEFT JOIN `core_url_rewrite` AS `url_rewrite` 
      ON url_rewrite.product_id = main_table.entity_id 
      AND url_rewrite.is_system = 1 
      AND url_rewrite.category_id IS NULL 
      AND url_rewrite.store_id = 1 
WHERE url_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'product/%'
```

(Notice the `LIKE` expression moved to `WHERE` clause)

This query returns the same results but is much faster - it executes in less than 1s on my production database.

**Question 2:**
Why there is such a difference in execution time between the 2 queries? Is there any issue with the `LIKE` expression put in the `LEFT JOIN` clause?

### Results from `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`:

Production database:

```
id    select_type    table        type      possible_keys                                                      key                                                key_len    ref            rows    filtered    Extra
 1     SIMPLE        w            index      PRIMARY                                                           IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID               2        NULL           642     100.00      Using index
 1     SIMPLE        main_table   eq_ref     PRIMARY                                                           PRIMARY                                              4        w.product_id     1     100.00      Using index
 1     SIMPLE        url_rewrite  ref        IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH,                                     FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID    5        const           10     100.02     
                                             FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID,
                                             FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID,
                                             UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH_IS_SYSTEM_STORE_ID
```

Development database:

```
id    select_type    table        type      possible_keys                                                      key                                                               key_len    ref            rows    filtered    Extra
 1     SIMPLE        w            index      PRIMARY                                                           IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID                              2        NULL           1009     100.00     Using index
 1     SIMPLE        main_table   eq_ref     PRIMARY                                                           PRIMARY                                                             4        w.product_id      1     100.00     Using index
 1     SIMPLE        url_rewrite  ref        IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH,                                     FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID    5        w.product_id     31     100.00     Using where     
                                             FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID,
                                             FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID,
                                             UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH_IS_SYSTEM_STORE_ID
```

**Tables sizes** (the same on both servers as development database is a dump of production database):

*catalog_product_entity*:
    Data       96 KB
    Indexes    88 KB
    Total      176 KB

*catalog_product_website*:
    Data      64 KB
    Indexes   16 KB
    Total     80 KB

*core_url_rewrite*:
    Data      5.5 MB
    Indexes   15.5 MB
    Total     21 MB

**Tables records count** (the same on both databases):
    catalog_product_entity    1009
    catalog_product_website   1009
    core_url_rewrite          34878

**Current time performance:**
    production database   50 seconds
    development database  0.1 second

**Desired time:**
    production database   1 second
    development database  0.1 second

### Indexes

**catalog_product_entity:**
 *PRIMARY* (entity_id, Type: BTREE, Unique: Yes)
 *IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID* (entity_type_id, Type: BTREE, Unique: No)

**catalog_product_website:**
 *PRIMARY* (product_id, Type: BTREE, Unique: Yes)
 *IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID* (website_id, Type: BTREE, Unique: No)

**core_url_rewrite:**
*PRIMARY* (url_rewrite_id, Type: BTREE, Unique: Yes)
*UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID* ((request_path, store_id), Type: BTREE, Unique: Yes)
*UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH_IS_SYSTEM_STORE_ID* ((id_path, is_system, store_id), Type: BTREE, Unique: Yes)
*IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_TARGET_PATH_STORE_ID* ((target_path, store_id), Type: BTREE, Unique: No)
*IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH* (id_path, Type: BTREE, Unique: No)
*IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_STORE_ID* (store_id, Type: BTREE, Unique: No)
*FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID* (category_id, Type: BTREE, Unique: No)
*FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID* (product_id, Type: BTREE, Unique: No)

### Final remarks:

The production server is not under a lot of stress - all other queries that I tested give similar results on both databases.

I cannot optimize (change) the query as it is hardcoded in the system, but I would like to know what is happening with my production database that this query is so much slower than development database.

I would be very grateful for explaining such strange behaviour of MySQL.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: First question: depend on how many users are using the production db. Second You need to examine the EXPLAIN ANALYZE to see the difference

Comment: Moving a condition on the `LEFT JOINed` table from `ON` to `WHERE` changes the behavior of the query. You won't get any of the rows that don't have a match in the second table, because `url_rewrite.id_path` will be `NULL` in those rows.

Comment: Make sure `id_path` has an index. Otherwise, that `LIKE` expression requires a full scan.

Comment: I edited the question, giving the information you requested.

Comment: As you can see @Barmar after my edit, there is already an index for `id_path`